# Add self-made certificate as trusted

Tags: ubuntu, certificate, certutil

I have a locally generated root certificate (Company_CA.pem) used to sign PDF files.
The signing process works fine and, after installing the public key on Adobe, I'm able to verify signatures and certificate.

Now, I need to do that in the terminal, So, I'm trying to use `pdfsig` on a Ubuntu 22.04 Docker image.

From my understanding, to have the certificate validation working, I must add the certificate to the Network Security Services (NSS) database. To do so, I have done the following

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install libnss3-tools
mkdir -p $HOME/.pki/nssdb
chmod -R 0700 $HOME/.pki 
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -N --empty-password
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n company -i /Company_CA.pem
```

The entire process was completed without errors. However, when I run `pdfsig` with a pdf file I get

```
- Signer Certificate Common Name: Sig D
- Signer full Distinguished Name: E=sig@company.com,CN=Sig D,O=Company,L=Marina Del Rey,ST=CA,C=USA
- Signing Time: Jan 11 2022 12:46:49
- Signing Hash Algorithm: SHA-256
- Signature Type: adbe.pkcs7.detached
- Signed Ranges: [0 - 115717], [120036 - 257774]
- Not total document signed
- Signature Validation: Signature is Valid.
- Certificate Validation: Certificate issuer isn't Trusted.
```

When I run `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L`, I get

```
Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI

company                                                      C,,
```

Why do I still get `Certificate issuer isn't Trusted.`. Am I missing something here?
How can I make myself (the certification issuer) trusted?

I have tried to play around with the `trustargs` (i.e, -t "P,P,P") but the outcome is still the same.

I'm running

```
pdfsig -v
pdfsig version 22.02.0
Copyright 2005-2022 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for pdfsig on 22.04 there is an option `-nssdir` to specify the certificate database location. Otherwise it uses /etc/pki/nssdb or the database in the default Firefox profile, i.e.  $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/*.default

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/pdfsig.1.html